# What are the differences between Autosar's SOME/IP and Unix-like's one?

Tags: linux, autosar

AUTOSAR specification defines its own SOME/IP like this:

[image]

This service-oriented protocol is located near the top over Ethernet stack

[image]

What is the difference among several systems (for example, AUTOSAR vs LINUX)?

Answer (score 1):

Both follow the same specification.

The difference is that when using AUTOSAR you get an abstraction layer (RTE) on top of SOME/IP. This abstraction layer is simular to what you would see in RPC technologies like gRPC or Java RMI.

When using other implementations of SOME/IP, this abstraction layer may look different (or may even be non existing).

The SOME/IP specification only define the protocol, not its programmatic API.